# Broken ice maker creating lots of frost in freezer

Tags: frost

My sister was cleaning out the ice cube container in the freezer and broke something. Now the ice maker does not work and is creating lots of frost. I noticed some sort of shut-off valve next to the fridge and turned it off but the water dispenser still gives water and the frost continues to build up.

It's a massive built in fridge so I'm not sure how to get behind it if that's what it requires to fix it. At this point I don't mind if the ice maker doesn't work, I just want the frost to stop. Thank you to all who take the time to reply.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The valve looks to be on to me, if the water dispenser is still providing water it is not turned off. It looks like a leak creating the ice it may be a plastic pipe that cracked , but turn the water off and verify there is no water in the dispenser, or the leak will probably continue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you say for certain based on the photos I posted that the shut-off valve is for both the dispenser and the ice maker?

Comment: I have installed several built ins different brand but they all had a single water feed even the ones that the ice maker itself was a separate unit inside the fridge. Sure it could be a separate water feed that would be quite unusual.

Comment: The valve was really hard to open and close. I kept wiggling it back and forth a few times and now it's still in basically the same position it was in the photos but now no more water is coming from the dispenser. Hopefully the frost will now stop. Thanks.